# Presigned Amazon S3 URLs created by eclipse not working

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I have having a very strange issue Using Eclipse With the Amazon Integration.

If i right click on an item in my bucket and generate a presigned URL and then use this URL in a browser i will get the following error:

> SignatureDoesNotMatch
>
> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method.

I have tried changing the keys in my amazon configuration, I have also tried with my server generating the key for the item but the access is also denied.

The credentials im using are the ones with the highest authority.

Is this a bug or is some special configuration needed? Like enabling the generation of presigned URLs or something.

If anyone has any experience on this it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite normal situation for Eclipse. I would suggest you to use SDK for that.

Comment: I have amazon tools installed in eclipse. I am opening my bucket on eclipse, right click on it, pick generate presigned url. this URL should give access to anyone for this especific element but it just tells me the signature is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Try to use SDK instead: http://aws.amazon.com/code?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1 or S3Fox...

Comment: I just found the problem, the eclipse one adds an extra / on the request.

Comment: Yes, that's why I started using Sublime Text!